# PHP Mysql JSON column contains

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json

I want to retrieve data from my MySQL database using PHP.

The database has a JSON column that contains an array.

I want to use a PHP array to search through the database and get only the answers that have one or more matches with the PHP array.

How do I ask the question?

**MySQL** *example*

```
ID  Name  JSON_Column

10  Name1 [ "Cst", "Söö", "K", "Hpbg", "Dg", "Khn", "Kil", "Ar" ]
11  Name2 [ "Då", "Söö", "K", "Tlg", "Dg", "Mra" ]
12  Name3 [ "Mras", "Söö", "K", "Hpbg" ]
13  Name4 [ "Cst", "Söö"]
14  Name5 [ "Rv", "Ar" ]
```

**PHP Array** *example*

```
$array = [ "Cst", "Kda", "Tu", "Hpbg", "Nyh", "Bkb" ]
```

**PHP qustion** *example*

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `tabel` WHERE JSON_Column = $array ";
```

**Result**

```
ID  Name  JSON_Column

10  Name1 [ "Cst", "Söö", "K", "Hpbg", "Dg", "Khn", "Kil", "Ar" ]
12  Name3 [ "Mras", "Söö", "K", "Hpbg" ]
13  Name4 [ "Cst", "Söö"]
```

Here I should get data back from MySQL because values ​​in the PHP array are in JSON_column.
One match is enough, but there may be more.

Below is the question I ask today to MySQL.
But I want to make it more efficient.

**PHP qustion** *today*

```
foreach ($array as $value) {
   $query = "SELECT * FROM `tabel` WHERE JSON_CONTAINS(JSON_Column->'$[*]', 
JSON_ARRAY('$value') )";

   $result = mysqli_query($con,$query);
            
   while ($data = mysqli_fetch_array($result )) {
      array_push($resultList, $data);
   }
}
```

*MySQL Version - 8.0.21*

Comment: MySQL can search JSON for single (scalar) value only, not for array elements. Parse your array in the query to separate values one value per row then search.

Comment: Hi, I am not specialist in PHP, but are you having any kind of errors with your  code? If there are errors, can you post them? Maybe it can help others to help you.

Comment: Show desired output for provided example.Specify precise MySQL version. Specify how many values must match - one? at least X? all?